# No inicia MySQL en Xampp

Tags: mysql, xampp

No sé que hacer, tengo este error en Xampp, no inicia MySQL, estoy en la escuela y necesito arreglarlo para trabajar. No sé porqué ocurre. Agredecería mucho su ayuda.
[image: Este es el error que me aparece]

Answer (score 0):

Ahí lo pone, parece que es por el puerto. Verifica que puedes usar X puerto, o cámbialo en el config.

- En el botón config de mysql en esa pantalla que pones abre el archivo **my.ini**
- Busca las líneas que ponen `port=3306`. Verifica que puedes usar ese puerto, pueda que necesites tocar el Firewall del PC. Igual prueba a cambiar de puerto, a veces eso lo soluciona. Puede ser que el 3306 ya esté siendo usado por otra instancia.
- Usa o instala XAMPP como admin.